# How run async method multiple times in separate threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I am newbie in using of await/async and windows phone 8.1 programming. I need to run async method simulateously in more than one thread. May be four, because my phone has four cores. But i cannot figure it out :-(

This is example of my async method.

```
public async Task GetFilesAsyncExample(StorageFolder root)
{
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folders = await root.GetFoldersAsync(); 
        //DO SOME WORK WITH FOLDERS//
}
```

Four threads can be ensured by using of a semaphore object, but how i can run it in simulatously running threads?

**EDIT:**
This is my code which explores folder structure and log metadata about files into database. I want to speed up execution of this code by calling method "async LogFilesFromFolderToDB(StorageFolder folder)" simulateously in separate thread for each folder.

```
 Stack<StorageFolder> foldersStack = new Stack<StorageFolder>();
            foldersStack.Push(root);
            while (foldersStack.Count > 0)
            {
                StorageFolder currentFolder = foldersStack.Pop();
                await LogFilesFromFolderToDB(null, currentFolder);// Every call of this method can be done in  a separate thread.
                IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folders = await currentFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
                for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count; i++)
                    foldersStack.Push(folders[i]);
            }
```

Method: async LogFilesFromFolderToDB(StorageFolder folder) looks like:

```
   async Task LogFilesFromFolderToDB(StorageFolder folder)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        //SOME ANOTHER CODE//
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and why do you want to run it simultaneously?

Comment: you can use ,Parallel.ForEach(folders, (currentFolder) => 
                                {   /// Your code })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parallel.Foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can help to resolve this issue.

Try the below code,

```
 public async Task GetFilesAsyncExample(StorageFolder root)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folders = await root.GetFoldersAsync();

        Parallel.ForEach(folders, (currentFolder) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("folder name:" + currentFolder.Name + " Files count" + currentFolder.GetFiles().Count());
        });
        //DO SOME WORK WITH FOLDERS//
    }
```

Comment: I think this cannot help me. I need to call simulateously method GetFilesAsyncExample() not iterate thru folders collection.

Comment: Here when you use Parallel, it will run your code into simultaneously as per available cores in your machine. Please follow the MSDN for Parallel.Foreach